# Having trouble with replacing strings in a phrase

Tags: java

I am having trouble replacing certain strings in a phrase. I have to replace "_" with < I  > and "< / I>" alternating. my code so far:

```
private String line; //The line to format

public TextFormatter(String lineToFormat) {
    line = lineToFormat;
}

/**
 * Finds the first single instance of str in line, starting at the postion start
 * <p>
 * @param str   the string of length 1 to find. Guaranteed to be length 1.
 * @param start the position to start searching. Guaranteed to be in the string line.
 * <p>
 * @return the index of first instance of str if string found or -1 otherwise.
 */
private int findString(String str, int start) {
    String phrase = line;
    int psn = phrase.indexOf(str, start);
    return psn;
}

/**
 * Count the number of times single instances of str appear in the line.
 * <p>
 * @param str the string to find. Guaranteed to be length 1.
 * <p>
 * @return the number of times the string appears in the line.
 */
private int countStrings(String str) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (line.charAt(i) == '_') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * Replaces all single instances of underscores in the line given by line with italics tags. There must be an even
 * number of underscores in the line, and they will be replaced by <I>, </I>, alternating.
 * <p>
 * @return the line with single instances of underscores replaced with
 * <I> tags or the original line if there are not an even number of underscores.
 * <p>
 */
public String convertItalics() {
    String toReturn = " ";

    if (countStrings("_") % 2 == 0) { //makes sure there is even number of "_"
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.indexOf("_") + i == line.indexOf("_")) {
                toReturn += line.replace("_", "<I>");
            }
        }
    } else if (countStrings("_") % 2 != 0) {
        toReturn += line.replace("_", " ");
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

I have the first methods down but I am having trouble with the convertItalics(). 
If I run my code I get it to replace the "_" but it doesn't alternate.

And if I have a phrase like "hello _my name is _chomez_", it doesn't replace any of the "_". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to those who left comments, my class is almost over so I'll check back when I have access to a computer and I have time, thank you all!

Comment: You should use an existing Markdown library.

Comment: You can consider using stacks

Comment: @SLaks I'm learning this in my class so I'm not really sure what that is, but I'll look it up, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment on the line, I would suggest to create an array of Strings from a line and loop over that line. 
Something like

```
String [] words = line.split(" ");
```

and later loop over these words and call your `countStrings(words[i]);`

```
public String convertItalics() {
    String toReturn = " ";
//***line below will never result in even number, since you are passing one "_", pass a whole word//***
    if (countStrings("_") % 2 == 0) { //makes sure there is even number of "_" 
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.indexOf("_") + i == line.indexOf("_")) {
                toReturn += line.replace("_", "<I>");
            }
        }
    } else if (countStrings("_") % 2 != 0) {
        toReturn += line.replace("_", " ");
    }


       return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Little note: Replace `***` with `//***` and close `convertItalics()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace characters in Java I would recommend to use  the method "replace"
for example:

```
 public class Test{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  String Str = new String("This is a long string");
  System.out.println(Str.replace('i', 'o'));
```

and this will basically replace the "i" by the "o". Also if you ever want to compare Strings in java you MUST use the method equals or equalsIgnoreCase and not ==, because you are comparing the number of characters and the right order and not the value of these Strings

I  hope this can help you!

Comment: he wants to replace chars depending on the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing screen scrapping? There are plenty of ways to do it. REGEX, string manipulation, stacks..etc.

This is one of the easy way.

```
String code = "hello _my name is _chomez_";
code = code.replace("_", "<li>");
```

**Now you successfully converted it to:**

```
hello <li>my name is <li>chomez<li>
```

Now just need to do the alternating closing tags.

```
int n = code.indexOf("<li>", code.indexOf("<li>") + 1);
code = code.substring(0,n+1) + "/" + code.substring(n+1);
```

**Now you have:**

```
hello <li>my name is </li>chomez<li>
```

If you have more than 3 tags to handle, just run through a loop, and replace all the even position tags as closing tags. Algorithm will be like, while there are tags, continue looping. If this is the 2nd, 4th, 6th.. (even positions tags), replace it with `</li>`

Answer (score 0):

The following code does exactly what you want:

```
public String convertItalics() 
{      
    String[] tags = {"</i>", "<i>"};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(line);

    int matchIndex = 0, counter = 0;        

    while((matchIndex = builder.indexOf("_", matchIndex)) > 0)
    {           
        counter++;              
        int length = builder.length();
        int endIndex = matchIndex + 1;

        if(endIndex > length ||  endIndex == 0) endIndex = length;

        builder.replace(matchIndex, endIndex, tags[counter % 2]);               
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

**E.g.** If the instance variable line equals to `"hello _my name_ is _chomez_ _l"` then the output will be:

```
hello <i>my name</i> is <i>chomez</i> <i>l
```

Hope this helps. Good luck and have fun programming!

Cheers,

Lofty